# Styling the dropdown search result

Tags: html, css

I am styling my id (#livesearch) in the following html so as to remove the light-grey rectangular border that comes enclosing **drop-down search results**  upon typing in the search box.
I have styled as it appears here below. But I am not able to have it gone.

livesearch.html

```css
#livesearch{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: red;
  height: 0px;
}





#livesearch a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
  display:block;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="johakim.css">
<script>
function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) {
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;

  }
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
</form>
<div id="livesearch"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I see you're a new contributor, please include only relevant code into your question, if you only need to style the dropdown the php and xml are not necessary, just change the `showResult` function to return some example output from the request instead of actually performing the request. I would edit and do these changes myself but I won't just because you've named your variables `$x,$y,$z,$q`.

Comment: Thank you  @ Gunther for your time, I have just change the **showResult** function and has worked.